# Using Activemq, spring for processed messages

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, message-queue

I want to make an application where:

- Users will send a message to queue
- Listener will listen messages of
  queue After processing of message in
  listener, listener
  will create a new response message
  and send it to another success or
  failure queue.

Questions:

- Should I use activemq as storage of processed messages?
- Will I be able to retrieve all messages of one queue without listing to them?
- Do we have any other solution for keeping all processed messages? I want to make a report of all processed messages present in success and failure queue.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a minimalistic sample [here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-jms.html) and [here](http://www.springbyexample.org/examples/simple-spring-jms-listener-config.html) for using ActiveMQ with Spring. About persistence options, read [ActiveMQ docs](http://activemq.apache.org/persistence.html). Also you might want to check out [these slides](http://www.springsource.com/files/uploads/all/pdf_files/news_event/Introduction_to_Apache_ActiveMQ_Webinar_Slides.pdf), to get a general overview on Spring JMS with ActiveMQ.

Answer (score 1):

ActiveMQ is not a storage facility, it is a message-passing facility.

If you want to store the messages after processing them then use a database.  For example, create a table that has a status flag for success or failure, then for reporting query that table.

Comment: thanks - Is there any library by which I can automate this? 
I want to avoid making tables for all models for storing in database. Depending upon my message object it should automatically store in database

Comment: You could have a table with two columns: status, and message.   Message would be a LOB that stored the serialized object.